# Clickable label in ASP .NET (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I've created a method that will return all of the links from a SQL table, and I can pass them to a label, but my problem is that those links are not clickable...
Is there a way to fix this? or maybe a way to pass the links into a table or something else?
Thank you!

the code looks like this:

```
service1.WebServiceLinks a1 = new service1.WebServiceLinks();
        string result = a1.GetLinks();


        Label1.Text = result;
```

This is the code for GetLinks() :

```
public static string GetLinks()
{

    string query = string.Format("SELECT Link FROM Linkovi");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = query;

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Append(reader["Link"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you need a link, use a `HyperLink` control rather than a `Label`.  What does your current code look like?  Are you using some sort of databound control to display the results?

Comment: What does the result of `a1.GetLinks()` look like? It is a collection of urls?  Does it have HTML in it for links?  Why is your web service just returning a big string, instead of some custom class that better reflects the information?

Comment: public static string GetLinks()
    {

        string query = string.Format("SELECT Link FROM Linkovi");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.CommandText = query;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Append(reader["Link"].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control of both ends of the web service, do yourself a favor and return meaningful information rather than just a giant string.  At the very least, return a collection of `List<string>`:

```
public static List<string> GetLinks()
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT Link FROM Linkovi");
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    try {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            result.Add(reader["Link"].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then for displaying the results, use something like a `Repeater` control bound to the result, with a `HyperLink` to display the clickable link:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="LinkDisplay" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="TheLink" runat="server"
        NavigateUrl='<%#Container.DataItem%>' Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And bind the repeater to the results in `Page_Load`:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    service1.WebServiceLinks a1 = new service1.WebServiceLinks();
    LinkDisplay.DataSource = a1.GetLinks();
    LinkDisplay.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: thank you mellamokb, but I dont know how to call the web method afterwards?

Comment: previously i just had this code:
   [WebMethod]

        public string GetLinks()
        {
            return ConnectionClass.GetLinks();
        }
    }

Comment: You would just need to have `public List<string> GetLinks()` instead.  The idea is you're not limited to just passing strings.  When you're passing data around with web services, just send data with as much context as possible.  Then the application should be responsible for the formatting.  Keep those concerns separate.

Comment: I understand that, but this is my first time working with c# and this web methods.. I dont know how to return this list...

Comment: Sure, I understand :).  So to start with, try using the code I put above for `ConnectionClass.GetLinks()` so it returns `List<string>`.  Then change your `[WebMethod] public List<string> GetLinks()` and see if it compiles?  I haven't tested my code above but it should get you close.  Can you try it out and see what you find?

Comment: I did that, but inside  [webmethod] public list<string> getlinks() {// I thing that in here I should call the method somehow? }

Comment: previously i had : return ConnectionClass.GetLinks();

Comment: You'll need to modify `ConnectionClass.GetLinks()` to the code I posted in my answer, which now returns `List<string>`.  Now the question I still have, we have no idea what `Link` field in `Linkovi` table contains. Is it urls? domain names? entire HTML snippets with anchor tags?

Comment: just some youtube links that look like this: http://www.youtube.com/embed/y6G8jr1lF1Y?rel=0

Comment: i dont know how to call the method that you've created..

Comment: You're already calling it... I just modified it.  It's your original method, same name and everything.  I just changed the return type and a couple lines in it.

Comment: Previously, in my connection class I had the method that was returning that big string. I called that method in the WebMethod like this:
 public string GetLinks()
        {
            return ConnectionClass.GetLinks();
        }

Comment: now, my web method looks like this:
  [WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetLinks()
        {
            
        }

Comment: inside the brackets there should be a code like in the previous WebMethod - return ConnectionClass.GetLinks(); ...

Comment: I dont know how to access the method from there

Comment: I tried writing [WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetLinks()
        {
            return ConnectionClass.GetLinks();

        }
and only the last link that was in the database was returned, and it  looked like this h t t p : / / w w w . y o u t u b e . c o m / e m b e d / 8 4 B d o Q r 4 f K g ? r e l = 0

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the label, why not use the [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control ? It renders a link(anchor  element).So you should be able to set the the clickable link on that.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it inside anchor tag

`<a href="your_link" >text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `<label>` tags must have a `for` attribute, referencing the `id` of the `<input>` element in question. Once you've got that, the `<label>` [should] be hot and clickable for any standards-compliant browser.

Here's an example of the sort of HTML markup you want:

```
<li><input id="options-rb1" type="checkbox" name="options" value="1"/><input<label for="options-rb1">&nbsp;Option 1</label></li>
<li><input id="options-rb2" type="checkbox" name="options" value="2"/><input<label for="options-rb2">&nbsp;Option 2</label></li>
<li><input id="options-rb3" type="checkbox" name="options" value="4"/><input<label for="options-rb3">&nbsp;Option 3</label></li>
<li><input id="options-rb4" type="checkbox" name="options" value="8"/><input<label for="options-rb4">&nbsp;Option 4</label></li>
```

Once should not that the `<label>` element need not be adjacent to (or even near) the `<input>` element to which it is tied.